# trouble parsing deeply nested attributes using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have been trying to parse this xml in c#

```
<schema uri=http://blah.com/schema >
   <itemGroups>
     <itemGroup description="itemGroup1 label="itemGroup1">
       <items>
        <item description="The best" itemId="1" label="Nutella"/>
        <item description="The worst" itemId="2" label="Vegemite"/>
       </items>
     </itemGroup>
   </itemGroups>
</schema>

\itemGroup1\Nutella-The best
\itemGroup1\Vegemite-The worst
```

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(myXml); //load your XML from file or stream

var rows = xDoc.Descendants("item").Select(x => string.Format(
                    @"\{0}-{1}\{2}-{3}",
                    x.Ancestors("itemGroup").First().Attribute("description").Value,
                    x.Ancestors("itemGroup").First().Attribute("label").Value,
                    x.Attribute("label").Value,
                    x.Attribute("description").Value));
```

Let's break down what we're doing:

- `xDoc.Descendants("item")` gets us all `<item>` elements in the entire document
- `Select(x => string.Format(format, args)` *projects* each `<item>` we got from the last operation into whatever format we specify in the lambda. In this case, a [formatted string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx).
- In terms of the XML tree, we're "sitting at" the `<item>` level, so we need to roll back up the tree to get the data for the parent group using `Ancestors`. Since that method returns a sequence of elements, we know we want the first (nearest to us) so we can read its attribute.

Now you have an `IEnumerable<string>`, one for each `<item>` in your XML document and the information in the format you specified:

```
foreach(string row in rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Having never parsed xml before, your explanation helped tremendously. Cheers